# I used MAX here to pick the maximum of the net worth of the billionaires, but it seems to not work in cases like, Bill Gates, Elon Musk etc

Tags: sparql, wikidata

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription (MAX(?billion) as ?billions) ?locationLabel (SAMPLE(?image) AS ?picture) ?page_titleEN
WHERE
{
  ?item wdt:P2218 ?worth.

  OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P19 ?location .}
  
  FILTER(?worth>1000000000).

  BIND(?worth/1000000000 AS ?billion).

  OPTIONAL {
    ?article schema:about ?item;

      schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>;

      schema:name ?page_titleEN.

    ?item rdfs:label ?LabelEN.

    FILTER((LANG(?LabelEN)) = "en")

  }

  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P18 ?image. }

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }

}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?billions ?locationLabel ?picture ?page_titleEN

ORDER BY DESC(?billions)
```

Comment: Do I need to use some other function? I want to pick the maximum of the net worth of billionaires

Comment: Show sample query output and explain what you think is wrong.

Comment: I guess he refers to the fact, that e.g. Bill Gates has an entry of 96,5 billion but in the result only the second highest with 86 is shown

Comment: It's just a matter of [truthy statements](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Truthy_statements). Do `?item p:P2218/ps:P2218 ?worth.` and you're done.